# group_by association in rails iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iteration

I have an iteration that creates a column with items.

```
Preference 
belongs_to :option

Option
has_many :preferences
belongs_to :category

Category 
has_many :options
```

So, when I iterate over the preferences I want to be able to group them by their options category.

```
  <% @preferences.group_by { |p| p.choice.category_id }.each do |pref| %>
      <div class="dutylog_column">
          <div class="dutylog_column_header"><span><%= category(pref) %></span></div>
          <ul class="dutylog_column_items">
            <% @users_logs.each do |dutylog| %>
              <li><%= dutylog.properties[pref.choice.try(:name)] %></li>
            <% end %>
            <%= content_tag :li, sum_column(pref.choice.try(:name)), class: "totals_row" if has_dutylogs? %>
              <li class="new_dutylog_entry"><%= f.text_field pref.choice.name, id: pref.choice.name, class: "sum_number" unless pref.choice.name.blank? %></li>
          </ul>
      </div> <%# dutylog_column %>
      <% end %>
```

div.dutylog_column is float: left; so each iteration creates a table like column.  Without grouping the preferences they appear to be random.  I'd like to order them...group them.

It seems the example I have above should work...but I get "undefined method 'options' for Array.

In playing with the more...Im realizing it is an issue with the hash of arrays that are returned by the group_by and trying to use individual attributes from each array.  I've updated the above code to reflect some changes.  The problem lies in where I am accessing array attributes via 'pref'.

```
<%= dutylog.properties[pref.choice.try(:name)] %>
```

The error is complaining about the choice association.  Which works fine, unless I use the group_by...which changes the output from the iteration.

Comment: Is this the exact code you're showing? There's a syntax error in the `group_by` line (extraneous parenthesis). Does the error say 'options' or 'option'?

Comment: error is singular 'option' ... the parenthesis was a typo

Comment: updated code, and added more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to user sort_by instead of group_by.

```
 @preferences.sort_by { |p| p.choice.category.position }.each do |pref|
```